# Can Android Device Manager only locate your phone if it is signed in to your Google Account?

Tags: samsung, hardware, photos

My phone was stolen two days ago, and I have only just had internet access to start looking up ways to find it - or, more specifically, at least recover the photographs on it.
While I had tried to back up the images by loading them onto my laptop, for some reason the phone wasn't showing up under "My Computer" so I gave up...ironically this was the day before it disappeared (it was a new phone).
I am pretty sure it was signed into my Google account, but I hadn't changed any other default settings. I tried searching for the phone on Android Device Mananger, but it can't locate it - presumably because the thief/ves wiped it? I guess I'm just hoping that maybe the device manager can't locate the phone because it's off...
Otherwise, is there any other way at all that I can retrieve my photographs?

Thank you (:

Comment: If your photos were not synced to an online service, like Google Photos, your only option is to hope you get the device back somehow, ADM cannot get your photos or other data regardless. If you had your Google account setup that is all that is required for ADM to locate or wipe your device

Comment: On a somewhat good note, modern devices have Factory Reset Protection, meaning if your Google account was setup, you had basic security (PIN or password) and someone doesn't know the password, your device is a worthless brick to them since even a factory reset will not clear FRP and the device will be unusable without your Google credentials.

Comment: It's true (about FRP) [since Android 5.1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/03/12/guide-what-is-android-5-1s-antitheft-device-protection-feature-and-how-do-i-use-it/)

Answer (score 0):

To use [Android Device Manager](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en) (ADM):

> Your device's location access need to be turned on and be signed in to your Google Account. Android Device Manager won't work for devices that are turned off or that don't have a mobile data or Wi-Fi connection.

No, you will not be able to retrieve photos remotely from your phone. [You can check whether your photos were uploaded by default to Google Storage](https://www.google.com/settings/storage). To prevent from losing photos in the future, [you can setup your phone to automatically upload photos to the cloud](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en&ref_topic=6156061&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1).